# Google Maps Marker Animation, with KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, knockout.js

I'm currently working on a map project with the Google Maps API, and KnockoutJS. I've managed to get most of my framework up and going, but the last piece of functionality is dodging me.

I'm trying to make it so when you click one of the pre-loaded locations on the left navigation bar, that it triggers the Google Maps marker animation, just like clicking on the actual marker does, as well as when filtering the list.

Here's my code so far:

```
    // Define all variables to satisfy strict mode.
var document;
var setTimeout;
var alert;
var ko;
var google;

// Parsing for dynamic background & quote.
function parseQuote(response) {
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = response.quoteText;
    document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = "Author - <b>" + response.quoteAuthor + "</b>";
}

// Specify all locations on map.
function model() {
    "use strict";
    var locations = [{
        title: "The Hub",
        lat: 39.521975,
        lng: -119.822078,
        id: "The Hub"
    }, {
        title: "The Jungle",
        lat: 39.524982,
        lng: -119.815983,
        id: "The Jungle"
    }, {
        title: "Bibo Coffee Company",
        lat: 39.536966,
        lng: -119.811042,
        id: "Bibo Coffee Company"
    }, {
        title: "Purple Bean",
        lat: 39.531135,
        lng: -119.833802,
        id: "Purple Bean"
    }, {
        title: "Sips Coffee and Tea",
        lat: 39.530438,
        lng: -119.814742,
        id: "Sips Coffee and Tea"
    }];
    return locations;
}

var listLocations = ko.observableArray(model());

// Initalize map location & position.
function initMap() {
    "use strict";
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: {
            lat: 39.529633,
            lng: -119.813803
        },
        zoom: 14
    });

// Define markers & content.
    listLocations().forEach(function (data) {

        var positionMk = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: positionMk,
            map: map,
            title: data.title,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: data.title
        });

        data.mapMarker = marker;

        marker.addListener("click", function () {
            data.triggerMarker(marker);
            listLocations().forEach(function (place) {
                if (data.title === place.title) {
                    place.openInfoWindow();
                } else {
                    place.closeInfoWindow();
                }
            });
        });

        map.addListener("click", function () {
            listLocations().forEach(function (place) {
                place.closeInfoWindow();
            });
        });

        var setMk = function (marker) {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            setTimeout(function () {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
            }, 750);
        };
        data.triggerMarker = setMk.bind();

        var openMk = function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        };
        data.openInfoWindow = openMk.bind();

        var closeMk = function () {
            infowindow.close(map, marker);
        };
        data.closeInfoWindow = closeMk.bind();

    });

}

// Define ViewModel for list and sorting of list.

function ViewModel() {
    "use strict";
    var self = {};

    self.placeList = ko.observableArray([]);

    listLocations().forEach(function (place) {
        place.visible = ko.observable(true);
        self.placeList.push(place);
    });

    self.filterValue = ko.observable("");

    self.filterList = ko.computed(function () {
        listLocations().forEach(function (place) {
            var searchParam = self.filterValue().toLowerCase();
            var toBeSearched = place.title.toLowerCase();

            place.visible(toBeSearched.indexOf(searchParam) > -1);

            if (place.mapMarker) {
                place.mapMarker.setVisible(toBeSearched.indexOf(searchParam) > -1);
            }

            if (place.visible() && searchParam && place.mapMarker) {
                place.triggerMarker(place.mapMarker);
            } else if (place.mapMarker) {
                place.closeInfoWindow();
            }
        });
    });

// Responsiveness for clicking locations on the list.
    self.onClickListener = function (data) {
        listLocations().forEach(function (place) {
            if (data.title === place.title) {
                place.openInfoWindow();
            } else {
                place.closeInfoWindow();
            }
        });
    };

    return self;
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

// Error handling for API's.
function forismaticError() {
    "use strict";
    alert("Forismatic API is unreachable, please check your internet connection and try again.");
}

function googleMapsError() {
    "use strict";
    alert("Google Maps API is unreachable, please check your internet connection and try again.");
}
```

Any insight that can be offered into this would be appreciated! I feel like it's obvious, but my tired brain is failing me.

***[In addition, here's a quick JSFiddle of the entire project as well.](https://jsfiddle.net/vmkkm0te/5/)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed to copy the line of code that triggers the animation to your `self.onClickListener` function:

```
self.onClickListener = function (data) {
                    listLocations().forEach(function (place) {
                        if (data.title === place.title) {
                            place.openInfoWindow();
                            place.triggerMarker(place.mapMarker);
                        } else {
                            place.closeInfoWindow();
                        }
                    });
                };
```

Comment: Wow, staring me in the face for sure! Thanks so much Ray!

Comment: Welcome :) Love the look and functionality of your project btw